# Run a method async while redirected to other pages

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I have a asp.net MVC application which uses J query and Ajax. And one of cshtml page which includes a  process running for a long time, so i made a async method and using ajax i was able to trigger it so hoping that the user can do some other work in a different page while the long process running in the background.

Its working fine when I'm working in the same page. But when i redirect to another page while the code is running in back end I'm not getting any output. Is it not possible to redirect while the another method is running? if so how can i get this done.

My c# contoller

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<JsonResult> TestAsyncPro(string ComponentId)
{
        try
        {
            await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(4000); 

            return Json(new { Success = true, Error = "" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { Success = false, Error = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

}

Ajax Call

```
$('#testasnc').click(function ()
{   
    $.ajax({
        url: '../AccountOpening/TestAsyncPro',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        data: { ComponentId: '21' },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.Success == true)
            {
                $(window).scrollTop(0);
                $("#alrtTestAsnc").show();  
                setTimeout(function () { $("#alrtTestAsnc").hide(); }, 5000);  
            } 
        }
    });

    var url = $("#RedirectTo").val();
    location.href = url;
   
});
```

Comment: A redirect to another page will abort any requests in progress. All script from current page is gone also so that `success` will never get called

Comment: So how can i do this? any work around would be helpful

Comment: have a look at using [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) or similar. As @charlietfl has said, the request ends when the page is exited. If you have a long running task, you can let Hangfire perform it in the background and update say a database when done

Comment: @GlynnHurrell is it free?

Comment: Yeh its 100% free. Open source I believe

Answer (score 2):

> so i made a async method and using ajax i was able to trigger it so hoping that the user can do some other work in a different page while the long process running in the background.

[That's not what `async` is for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net#asynchronous-code-is-not-a-silver-bullet).

What you really want is an independent background worker. ASP.NET works by handling HTTP requests, and you want some work done *outside* an HTTP request (i.e., after the HTTP request completes). Thus, the work you want to do is not a natural fit for ASP.NET.

I usually recommend a proper distributed system design for this kind of situation. This means adding a reliable queue (Azure Queue / Amazon SQS / etc), and a separate backend processor (Azure Function / Amazon Lambda / ASP.NET Core background service / Win32 service / etc). Then the ASP.NET handler will enqueue the background work to do to the queue, and return a redirect; the backend processor will pick up the work from the queue and actually execute it.

Hangfire is a low-entry solution; it uses a database as a reliable queue and has an in-process backend processor (similar to ASP.NET Core background service hosted in an ASP.NET Core HTTP application). There are some tradeoffs with this approach (e.g., you can't scale your backend independently), but it's an OK solution if you're not on ASP.NET Core yet.